# sifr in Chrome only displaying tiny text

Tags: sifr, google-chrome

I have sifr v3 revision 419 running fabulously on IE7, FF3 and Safari, but in Chrome and FF2 the text renders really tiny!  Anyone got any clues why this is happening?  I have specified the h1 and .sIFR-active h1 as both 24px.  Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found the error so am posting it here in case anyone else gets the same problem.  I forgot the `line-height: 1em;` in `.sIFR-active h1`.  That did it alright...!

Comment: If you upgrade to r436 you'll no longer need to specify `line-height`, and you'll get IE8 compatibility.

Comment: I'm using the coffee cup software to generate the swf and it only does v419 compatible movies.  So will have to stick with it for now.  Thanks for the tip tho!